# Why my minor mode bindings do not get precedence over global/major mode bindings? BUG?

Tags: key-bindings, minor-mode

EDIT: ANSWER

The cause for the problem in this question was pointed out [in the Emacs mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2020-09/msg02228.html). It is due to the `(kbd ...)` forms not getting evaluated because the keymap in the `define-minor-mode` is passed as a quoted list.
The `(kbd ...)` forms can be used by using a [backquoted list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote) and then placing a `,` before each `(kbd ...)` form so that they get evaluated.

END EDIT

I know there are similar questions like mine, but I could not find an answer to my question.

This question was edited (below) because it appears to be a bug (please confirm).

I want my minor-mode bindings to get precedence over the pdf-view major mode bindings.

I define my minor mode with the following code:

```
(define-minor-mode pdf-continuous-scroll-mode
  "Emulate continuous scroll with two synchronized buffers"
  nil
  " Continuous"
  '(((kbd "j") . (lambda () (interactive) (print "pushed j")))
    ((kbd "k") . (lambda () (interactive) (print "pushed k")))
    ((kbd "C-n") . (lambda () (interactive) (print "pushed C-n")))
    ((kbd "C-p") . (lambda () (interactive)(print "pushed C-p"))))
  (print "loaded minor mode"))
```

Now when I evaluate this while I am viewing a document with PDF-tools and enable the minor mode, then the `j`/`k` bindings work but the `C-n/C-p` bindings do not because Emacs still uses the pdf-view major mode keybindings (i.e. it scrolls the document).
I find [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html) that minor-mode keymaps should have highest precedence behind overlay keymaps. I checked if maybe there is some overlay keymap used in PDF-tools but I could not find one.

Can anybody explain why my minor mode bindings do not get precedence over de pdf-view major mode bindings?

EDITS

1. I find the `C-n` and `C-p` do not even get precedence over the global-keymap. I can just start emacs using `emacs -Q`, evaluate the code and activate the minor mode. Then still `C-n` and `C-p` do not work. Please someone confirm this is a bug, then I will report the bug.

END EDIT

Comment: Please post the Spacemacs question separately. One question per question. Thx.

Comment: I created a bug report and removed the Spacemacs question. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for creating the bug report. I expect this will be fixed soon - shouldn't be complicated, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a bug.

If you don't use that alist as the `KEYMAP` arg, but instead you create a keymap, assign it to a variable, use `define-key` with `(kbd "C-n")` etc., and use that variable as the `KEYMAP` arg, then it works.

Please consider using `M-x report-emacs-bug`, to report this.

```lisp
(setq toto-map (make-sparse-keymap))
(defun foo () "..." (interactive) (message "my C-n"))
(define-key toto-map (kbd "C-n") 'foo)
(define-minor-mode pdf-continuous-scroll-mode
  "Emulate continuous scroll with two synchronized buffers"
  nil
  " Continuous"
  toto-map
  (print "loaded minor mode"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The workaround is working fine indeed. I have reported a bug using the `report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: A discussion about this being a bug or not can be found [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2020-09/msg02228.html)